# Finding final position of SVG path element in Python

Tags: python, svg

I am currently messing around with the *svgwrite* module and I would like to calculate the end position of a path element using its string.
For example:

`"m151,200 105,60 M250,200 A100,100 0 1,1 200,0 c0,0 0,0 -16,120 c0,0 0,0 -84,46 c-4,-5 0,0 -84,-46 c-20,0 0,0 -16,-120 z"`

I created a function to do just this, and it works, but it is a bit clunky.

```py
def pathPos(path, debug=0): #Gets ending position of path
    posCrawl = {'m':lambda a: [list(map(int, i.split(','))) for i in a[1:].split()[0::1]], #Find pos argment based on instruction
                'l':lambda a: [list(map(int, i.split(','))) for i in a[1:].split()[0::1]],
                'h':lambda a: [(int(i), 0) for i in a[1:].split()[0::1]],
                'v':lambda a: [(0, int(i)) for i in a[1:].split()[0::1]],
                'c':lambda a: [list(map(int, i.split(','))) for i in a[1:].split()[2::3]],
                's':lambda a: [list(map(int, i.split(','))) for i in a[1:].split()[1::2]],
                'q':lambda a: [list(map(int, i.split(','))) for i in a[1:].split()[1::2]],
                't':lambda a: [list(map(int, i.split(','))) for i in a[1:].split()[0::1]],
                'a':lambda a: [list(map(int, i.split(','))) for i in a[1:].split()[3::4]]}
    args = re.findall("([MmLlZzHhVvCcSsQqTtAa][^MmLlZzHhVvCcSsQqTtAa]*)", path) #Create list of all path instructions with their arguments
    initialPos = [0,0]
    currentPos = [0,0]
    for arg in args:
        if debug:
            print(arg)
        if arg[0].isupper(): #Check if instruction is absolute...
            if arg[0].lower() == 'm': #M/m is a special case because it sets the initial position that Z/z returns to
                initialPos = posCrawl['m'](arg)[0] #absolute sets value
                currentPos = posCrawl['m'](arg)[-1]
            elif arg[0].lower() == 'z':
                currentPos = initialPos #Special case that closes path (returns to initial position)
            else:
                currentPos = posCrawl[arg[0].lower()](arg)[-1]
        elif arg[0].islower():#...or relative
            if arg[0].lower() == 'm':
                initialPos = [sum(x) for x in zip(initialPos, posCrawl['m'](arg)[0])] #relative adds value
                currentPos = [sum(x) for x in zip(*(posCrawl['m'](arg)+[currentPos]))]
            elif arg[0].lower() == 'z':
                currentPos = initialPos
            else:
                currentPos = [sum(x) for x in zip(*(posCrawl[arg[0]](arg)+[currentPos]))]
        if debug:
            print(currentPos)
            print()
    print(currentPos)
```

How can I improve it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you should ask it on codereview.stackexchange.com rather than here.

Comment: Ok, Fair enough. I'll try over there. Thanks.